# Proof by induction for $f^{n+1}(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)x^2}}$

Tags: analysis, induction

Look at the following function *f*: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$

Show with the complete induction that the recursive ( given by $f^1:=f$ and $f^{n+1}:=f\circ f^n$) composition $f^n$ from $f$ has the following explicit illustration:

$f^n(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2}}$

**My solution:**

**Base case:** For $n=1$

$f^1(x)=f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+1\cdot x^2}}$

**Inductive step:**

$f^{n+1}(x)=(f\circ f^n)(x)=f(f^n(x))=\frac{f^n(x)}{\sqrt{1+(f^n(x))^2}}$

So now I would have to plug in $f^n(x)$ for $x$ I think.

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2}}$ $\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2}}}{\sqrt{{1+(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2}}})^2}}$ But how do I get from there to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+(n+1)x^2}}$ = $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2+x^2}}$

I have encountered this problem in an old math exam from 2016 and it is of interest to me because I am currently practicing a lot of exercises related to convergences and mathematical induction.

Any hints guiding me to the right direction I much appreciate.

Comment: I could not think of a better title for this question due to my limited english skills.

Comment: Yes, which is it ? $n$ or $n+1$ ?

Comment: Better is to write $$f^{(n)}$$

Comment: I have edited it. I have also forgot to put a root before the 1 at the very end but I dont know how to write it.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I am a bit confused. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't substitute correctly when you plugged in $f^n$.  Perhaps you should take it a bit at a time.  Substitute for $f^n$ in the denominator only, and simplify.  Then substitute in the numerator and simplify again.

Comment: *an old math exam from 2016* That's not old!

Comment: @Shaun What would you consider to be an old math exam?

Comment: I don't know; something from, say, 2006, not 2016, because that's recent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
(f\circ f^n)(x)&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2}} }{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{x^2}{1+nx^2}}}\\
& = \dfrac{ \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+nx^2}} }{\sqrt{\dfrac{1+nx^2+x^2}{1+nx^2}}}\\
&  =\dfrac{x}{ \sqrt{1+nx^2+x^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{x}{ \sqrt{1+(n+1)x^2}}\\
&= f^{n+1}(x)
\end{align}